# *ngFor local variable for each element

Tags: angular

I have a function that I need to call for each element that will produce 2 new outputs. For example

```
list = [{a : 1, b: 2}, {a:3, b: 4}]
```

my html would be

```
<div *ngFor="#item of list">{{item.c}}, {{item.d}}</div>
```

If you notice, I am displaying c and d. Those does not exist in the original list, but I want to call a function and calculate them so I can display them. I do not want to call the function twice. The value of d = a + b + c. This means that it depends on c

I need my template to be like this

```
<div *ngFor="#item of list; #newItem=calculate(item)">{{newItem.c}}, {{newItem.d}}</div>
```

I know that I can not use local variables for this, but can you think of another solution?

Live example:

(a) is an item price
(b) is shipping costs
(c) is a sales tax calculated based on (a)
(d) is final price = a + b + c

I want to display:

```
Price: {{a}}
Taxes: {{c}}
Shipping {{b}}
Final Price: {{d}}
```

Comment: Have you managed it somehow? I am struggling with same thing since a couple of days.

Answer (score 3):

Prepare the data before you use it in `*ngFor`

```
list.forEach((item) => {
  item.newItem = calculate(item);
})
```

```
<div *ngFor="let item of list">{{item.newItem.c}}, {{item.newItem.d}}</div>
```

Comment: I know that, but this is not what I am looking for. Sorry! Iff the data is not be used, I need to scope it at the template variable. This is besides that I do not want to change the original list.

Comment: I would like to generate unique name based on UUID but the syntax fails. `<tr *ngFor="let item of items; let name = getSelectBoxName();">`. I cannot use index as I want to delete some item and using index doesnt work well. How can we achive this in Angular 4.4.6?

Comment: @MuraliMurugesan not sure what you try to accomplish, but there is no way to declare arbitrary variables inside the `*ngFor="..."` expression. You can use `getSelectBoxName()` in bindings on items created by `*ngFor`, but binding to methods is usually a bad idea. It's better to create an array with the required values beforehand and then just refer to the array using an index like `*ngFor="let item of items; let idx = index"` (where `index` is a supported property of `*ngFor`)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, Thanks for a quick response. I am dynamically generating dropdowns and they are wrapped as componenet, which has some input bindings. Adding and removing the new components are managed from parent component with #templateRef variable and calling its method using ViewChildren, QueryList collection. But the QueryList, doesnot change when the underlying array is updated. So facing issue with index based name :(

Comment: @MuraliMurugesan I don't really understand where the problem is. I'd suggest to create a new question with more code.

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to create a dedicated sub component to display item:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'item',
  template: `
    {{item.c}}, {{item.d}}
  `
})
export class ItemComponent {
  @Input()
  set item(item) {
    this._item = this.calculate(item);
  }

  calculate(item) {
    return ...
  }

  get item() {
    return this._item;
  }
}
```

and its use:

```
@Component({
  (...)
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="#item of list">
      <item [item]="item"></item>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [ ItemComponent'
])
(...)
```

Comment: I like that. Nice try, but c & b may come some in the middle between a & b. I want it to be flexible so that I may display them at any order. I think angular need to be flexible enough to do that. The solution that is available is setting a new variable in the component code and then find each element while loading or update the actual element and this is also not desired.

Comment: Can your solution be flexible to do something like this?

Comment: Could you give a concrete sample of what you want to do? ;-) In fact, you can provide every hints you want to the `ItemComponent` with other `@Input`. They can be use then within the `calculateItem`... Another question where does `c` come from? You said: "This means that it (d) depends on c"...